# Why are the buttons not showing up in the frame?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a simple program to switch scenes in JavaFX. I created my button objects, added them to the layout, added the layout to the scene, but for some reason the buttons aren't showing up at all. The label shows up. Here's my code:

```
package switching.scenes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SwitchingScenes extends Application {

private Scene scene1, scene2, scene3;
private Button button1, button2, button3;
private Label label1, label2, label3;
private VBox layout1, layout2, layout3;
private Stage frame;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    frame = primaryStage;

    // Create buttons
    button1 = new Button("Go to scene 1");
    button2 = new Button("Go to scene 2");
    button3 = new Button("Go to scene 3");

    // Button action listener
    button1.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene1));
    button2.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene2));
    button3.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene3));

    // Create labels
    label1 = new Label("You are at scene 1");
    label2 = new Label("You are at scene 2");
    label3 = new Label("You are at scene 3");

    // Create layouts
    layout1 = new VBox(20);
    layout2 = new VBox(20);
    layout3 = new VBox(20);

    // Add elements to each layout
    layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button2, button3);
    layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2, button1, button3);
    layout3.getChildren().addAll(label3, button1, button2);

    // Create scenes
    scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 400,400);
    scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 400,400);
    scene3 = new Scene(layout3, 400,400);

    frame.setScene(scene1);
    frame.setTitle("Title");
    frame.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

 }
```

Comment: No node can be part of more than one scene. ["A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph. Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of a Parent, or as the clip of a Node."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create **unique** button nodes for each scene. Check code below

```
package switching.scenes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SwitchingScenes extends Application {

    private Scene scene1, scene2, scene3;
    private Button button2_1, button3_1,button1_2, button3_2,button1_3, button2_3;
    private Label label1, label2, label3;
    private VBox layout1, layout2, layout3;
    private Stage frame;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        frame = primaryStage;

        // Create buttons
        button1_2 = new Button("Go to scene 1");button1_3 = new Button("Go to scene 1");
        button2_1 = new Button("Go to scene 2");button2_3 = new Button("Go to scene 2");
        button3_1 = new Button("Go to scene 3");button3_2 = new Button("Go to scene 3");

        // Button action listener
        button1_2.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene1));button1_3.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene1));
        button2_1.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene2));button2_3.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene2));
        button3_1.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene3));button3_2.setOnAction(e -> frame.setScene(scene3));

        // Create labels
        label1 = new Label("You are at scene 1");
        label2 = new Label("You are at scene 2");
        label3 = new Label("You are at scene 3");

        // Create layouts
        layout1 = new VBox(20);
        layout2 = new VBox(20);
        layout3 = new VBox(20);

        // Add elements to each layout
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(label1, button2_1, button3_1);
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2, button1_2, button3_2);
        layout3.getChildren().addAll(label3, button1_3, button2_3);

        // Create scenes
        scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 400,400);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 400,400);
    scene3 = new Scene(layout3, 400,400);

        frame.setScene(scene1);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I used an Underscore "_" to represent the **scene number**.Hope that was helpful.